# Splitting paired values in a CSV

Tags: c#, linq, csv, lookup

I have a situation where the requirements have changed after a while. The piece of code in question is reading a huge CSV file with row representing a user through an identifier and a pair(s) of system/username.

```
hgulzar;ActiveDirectory1;hgulzar@dev.domain.de;ActiveDirectory2;hgulzar@dev-ref.de
someusr;ActiveDirectory1;someusr@dev.domain.de;ActiveDirectory1;someusr@dev-ref.de
usrthre;ActiveDirectory1;usrthr1@dev.domain.de;ActiveDirectory1;usrthr2@dev-ref.de;ActiveDirectory1;usrthr3@dev.domain.de
```

Originally, it was a rule that each system was to be unique but now the requirement has changed and above sample row #2 and #3 are also valid. Only exception now is that there cannot be same username for same system (pure duplicate)

Below, I read the file line-by-line and the `dataRow` is the array loaded with splitted string.

```
// Data line
var dataRow = localReadLine.Split(new[] { ToolSettings.RightsSeperator }, StringSplitOptions.None);

// Trim each element
Array.ForEach(dataRow, x => dataRow[Array.IndexOf(dataRow, x)] = x.Trim());
```

Then, I load up an anonymous type holding identifier and pairs

```
// Extract System/Username pairs
var lookup = dataRow.Skip(1).Select((data, index) => new
{
    lookup = index % 2,
    index,
    data
}).ToLookup(d => d.lookup);
```

Here is debugging session screen shots of structure:

First row:
[image: Good row lookup]

Second row that'll fail at next step
[image: Bad row lookup]

Then, as per original requirements, I was converting the anonymous type to a filtered dictionary with the system name as key and this now fails.

```
// Check for duplicates
var rights = lookup[0].Join(lookup[1], system => system.index + 1, username => username.index, (system, username) => new
{
    system = system.data,
    useraname = username.data
}).Where(d => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.system)).ToDictionary(d => d.system, d => d.useraname);

// rights => Key = System Identifier, Value = Username
```

Screen shot of first row final form:
[image: Good row result]

Second row fails as `Key is already in dictionary' for obvious reason.

I need to have this code so that it only fails for a situation like this:

```
dummyUser;ActiveDirectory1;dummy1@dev.domain.de;ActiveDirectory1;dummy1@dev.domain.de
```

Meaning, system and name both repeated. Everything else is acceptable. I need to iterate the result and that's why I trying to add a sort of counter as a key and a tuple of  for value of the resultant dictionary.

Help/pointer appreciated.

Bye!

**UPDATE**

For some reason this question was down-voted for being a code assignment. I guess I added too much detail trying to explaining my one liner question. Though it is still a simple question.

Anyways, I finally came to the solution after reading the better inputs by some. Here is how I solved the issue:

```
var rights = lookup[0].Join(lookup[1], system => system.index + 1, username => username.index, (system, username) => new
{
    system = system.data,
    useraname = username.data
}).Where(d => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.system)).Select(d => new Tuple<string, string>(d.system, d.useraname)).ToList();
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.  Take your best shot and come back with _specific_ problems.

Comment: I'd use a list of KeyValuePairs (`List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`) which would stop the error `Key is already in dictionary' and you could still iterate the list. You would then need to check for exact duplicates within the list.

Comment: The question is as direct and to the point as possible. The ToDictionary is failing due to repeated key which is desired. Need to have something else instead that would still allow to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you split your solution in two steps: extraction and validation

```
var separator = new []{ ';' };
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\sample.txt")
    .Select(line =>
    {
        var values = line.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);
        return new
        {
            User  = values[0],
            Items = values.Skip(1)
                .Select ((value, index) => new { Number = index / 2, Value = value })
                .GroupBy( group => group.Number)
                .Select ( group => new
                {
                    System   = group.First().Value,
                    UserName = group.Last ().Value
                })
                .ToArray()
        };
    })
    .ToArray();

// This will fail for duplicated system/username
if (lines.Any(line => line.Items.GroupBy(i => i.System + i.UserName)
                                .Any    (g => g.Count() > 1)))
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Duplicated data");
```